# Integrability of $F(x) = \int_0^1 f(k) \exp(i g(k) x) dk$ when $g(k)$ has poles

Tags: integration

Consider the integral
$$F(x) = \int_0^1 f(k) \exp(i g(k) x) dk$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit, and $g(k)$ is a real function that may have poles in the integration interval.

I suspect the following is true, but can't prove it

> $F(x)$ exists for all $x$ $\implies$ $f(k)$ has a zero wherever $g(k)$ has a pole

Is it true?